# Filter data using temp table instead of join and filter with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, temp-tables

Using SQL Server 2012 I have 2 tables (t1 and t2). there are millions of records in both table. there is a date field in both of them.

I'm using this query

```
insert into dumpTable
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.datefield = t2.datetield
where t1.datefield = '2015-01-01'
```

The query takes one hours to run

I also tried

```
insert into dumpTable
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.datefield = t2.datetield 
    and t1.datefield = '2015-01-01' and t2.datefield = '2015-01-01'
```

I changed it to below to filter the records before join and ran in 5 minutes

```
select * into #t1 from t1 where datefield = '2015-01-01'
select * into #t2 from t2 where datefield = '2015-01-01'

insert into dumpTable
select * from #t1 inner join #t2 on #t1.datefield = #t2.datetield
```

1. How can you explain this? Isn't optimizer smart enough to filter
   both tables when reading the data set before joining them?
2. Is there any alternative instead of using temp table?

Comment: Can you include your execution plan? My hunch is the first one mistakenly chose a Nested Loop while the second one goes with a much more appropriate Hash Match.

Comment: Presumably that second temp table is really `#t2`.

Comment: I corrected it. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Zoff said, this is probably the query optimizer choosing a nested loops join type instead of a hash join type. It would be helpful for you to provide us the estimated execution plan for query, but failing that, try forcing the hash join type as in the query below and see if that runs faster.

```
insert into dumpTable
select * from t1 inner hash join t2 on t1.datefield = t2.datetield
where t1.datefield = '2015-01-01'
```

In the case of this query, it's probably acceptable to go on using this type of hint, but ultimately indexes may need to be adjusted and statistics updated to form a better long term solution.

Comment: I used the hint and it ran in 15 seconds.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The queries on the temp tables probably ran faster because the statistics on the table are accurate.  This helps SQL Server choose the right execution plan.

For this query:

```
insert into dumpTable
    select *
    from t1 inner join
         t2
         on t1.datefield = t2.datetield
    where t1.datefield = '2015-01-01';
```

You can create two indexes:  `t1(datefield)`, and `t2(datefield)`.  These should speed the query.

Comment: I have index on the join field. both tables also have columnstore index. I don't understand why lack of accurate statistics could cause so big difference.

Comment: You would have to look at the two execution plans to see the difference.